# Set autoscale limits on plot to have buffer around all points

Tags: limit, matplotlib

I would like to plot a set of points using pyplot in matplotlib but have none of the points be on the edge of my axes.  The autoscale (or something) sets the `xlim` and `ylim` such that often the first and last points lie at `x = xmin` or `xmax` making it difficult to read in some situations.

This is more often problematic with `loglog()` or `semilog()` plots because the autoscale would like `xmin` and `xmax` to be exact powers of ten, but if my data contains only three points, e.g. at `xdata = [10**2,10**3,10**4]` then the first and last points will lie on the border of the plot.

### Attempted Workaround

This is my solution to add a 10% buffer to either side of the graph.  But is there a way to do this more elegantly or automatically?

```
from numpy import array, log10
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

xdata = array([10**2,10**3,10**4])
ydata = xdata**2

figure()
loglog(xdata,ydata,'.')
xmin,xmax = xlim()
xbuff = 0.1*log10(xmax/xmin)
xlim(xmin*10**(-xbuff),xmax*10**(xbuff))
```

I am hoping for a one- or two-line solution that I can easily use whenever I make a plot like this.

### Linear Plot

To make clear what I'm doing in my workaround, I should add an example in linear space (instead of log space):

```
plot(xdata,ydata)
xmin,xmax = xlim()
xbuff = 0.1*(xmax-xmin)
xlim(xmin-xbuff,xmax+xbuff))
```

which is identical to the previous example but for a linear axis.

### Limits too large

A related problem is that sometimes the limits are too large.  Say my data is something like `ydata = xdata**0.25` so that the variance in the range is much less than a decade but ends at exactly `10**1`.  Then, the autoscale `ylim` are `10**0` to `10**1` though the data are only in the top portion of the plot.  Using my workaround above, I can increase `ymax` so that the third point is fully within the limits but I don't know how to *increase* `ymin` so that there is less whitespace at the lower portion of my plot.  i.e., the point is that I don't always want to spread my limits apart but would just like to have some constant (or proportional) buffer around all my points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@askewchan I just succesfully achieved how to change matplotlib settings by editing matplotlibrc configuration file and running python directly from terminal. <s>Don't know the reason yet, but matplotlibrc is not working when I run python from spyder3 (my IDE).</s> Just follow steps here [matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

**1) Solution one (default for all plots)**

Try put this in matplotlibrc and you will see the buffer increase:

```
axes.xmargin        : 0.1  # x margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
axes.ymargin        : 0.1  # y margin See `axes.Axes.margins`
```

Values must be between 0 and 1.

**Obs.:** Due to bugs, scale is not correctly working yet. It'll be fixed for matplotlib 1.5 (mine is 1.4.3 yet...). More info:

- [axes.xmargin/ymargin rcParam behaves differently than pyplot.margins() #2298](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2298)
- [Better auto-selection of axis limits #4891](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4891)

**2) Solution two (individually for each plot inside the code)**

There is also the margins function (for put directly in the code). Example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
t = np.linspace(-6,6,1000)
plt.plot(t,np.sin(t))
plt.margins(x=0.1, y=0.1)
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

**Obs.:** Here scale is working (0.1 will increase 10% of buffer before and after x-range and y-range).

Comment: If someone else figure out how margins scale works please point for me and I will update my answer to be more complete.

Comment: Reading this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2298 seems like that this scale behavior is a bug. Seems like it will be fixed for matplotlib 1.5 (mine is 1.4.3 yet...).

Comment: Maybe another useful thread here 
 [Better auto-selection of axis limits #4891](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4891)

Comment: I just updated my answer with this comments content.

Answer (score 3):

A [similar question](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg15244.html) was posed to the matplotlib-users list earlier this year. The most promising solution involves implementing a Locator (based on [MaxNLocator](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=locator#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) in this case) to override MaxNLocator.view_limits.