# How to increase plot y-range iwith matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to know how to set matplotlib to use 10% of y-range function over and below my figure.

I did the following code to solve this:

```
def Y_LIM(vetor):
    lim_inf = np.min(vetor)
    lim_sup = np.max(vetor)
    tam = lim_sup - lim_inf
    return [lim_inf-tam/10, lim_sup+tam/10]
```

Example: plotting sin() would go from -1 to 1 in y axis. Using my function, it'll go from -1.1 to 1.1 (10% increase). See below:

```
t = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)    
plt.ylim(Y_LIM(np.sin(t)))
plt.plot(t,np.sin(t))
```

Problem solved. But I would not like to use this everytime I plot something. Is there a way to 'natively' solve this issue?

Comment: I think maybe now's the time to go try to implement the solution suggested in the answer to this old question [Set autoscale limits on plot to have buffer around all points](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6118598/1730674). I'll update here if I get around to it.

Comment: @askewchan thanks for your link. I just found matplotlibrc configuration file and trying figure out if I could use this for configure matplotlib the way I want. Followed steps here http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html but failed for some reason...
I tested just one feature:
1) Created .config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc in my /home
2) Put
`savefig.dpi         : 1200      # figure dots per inch`
as argument in the file.

Didn't worked...

Comment: Obs.: I've used dpi just to test if the file would work, but there must be one option to 'loose' or 'tight' the plot

Comment: I don't know of any setting that would change the auto zoom level, but if you find one please let me know (and post an answer at the other question!)